# How to check TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION sensor availability in android device?

Tags: android, sensors, sensormanager, user-activity

I have used the below code to check the TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION sensor availability.

```
    SensorManager mSensorManager = (SensorManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    List<Sensor> sensors = mSensorManager
            .getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION);

    boolean isSensorAvailable = Boolean.valueOf(sensors.size() > 0);
```

I have tested in three different devices. All the devices returning false.

In doc they given that TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION Constants added in API 18. How to check this sensor availability to version prior to 18. 
Correct me to get the right sensor availability status.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation, it's suggested to check the availability like this:

```
if (mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION) != null){
    mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION);
}
```

For version prior to 18, it'll always be null since it's not defined yet.

Since the significant motion sensors is based on accelerometer, the reason all the devices you tested are returning false when checking this sensor might be that the manufactures didn't implement this software sensor using the accelerometer. But you can always implement something similar yourself.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Anhong, I have accelerometer, yet the above returns null. Is there a way to wakeup from sleep with simple accelerometer ?

Comment: Having accelerometer doesn't mean you have other types of software sensors - so you might want to try out each sensor in the category and use the ones available